# Two customize cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, cells

I would like to know if it's possible to have 2 customize cells in one `UITableView` ?

Because I would like to have two different type of cells in one view : the first row will be big (with white background on screenshot), and after simple row (with red background on screenshot).

Tell me if that's possible or not, and how to make that :)

I let you see what I want to make :

http://www.noelshack.com/2015-13-1427415385-sans-titre.png

Or maybe put a UIView for big label, and after table cell ?

Comment: You can have thousands of different customized cells in the same table view.

Comment: @rmaddy Really ? and you can choose the size of their cells ? So it's possible to realize my screenshot ?

Comment: Absolutely. Read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" in the docs.

Comment: And do [some searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+different+cell+types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches, assuming that the big screenshot is only on the first row. You could set the table view's property

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = myHugeImage;
```

Otherwise, if you design 2 rows using nibs and custom classes, you'll need to call the following in viewDidLoad. Do note that custom classes must be subclasses of UITableViewCell

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"bigrow" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"big"]
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"normal row" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"normal"]
```

If you used classes and no nibs, then you would use registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier
If you used classes and designed the cell directly inside the prototype cell, then neither of those calls are necessary.

Lastly, inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    BigRowCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"big" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return c;
}
SmallRowCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"normal" forIndexPath:indexPath];
return c;
```